# How does "temperature" work in vacuum?

Tags: temperature, thermal, thermal-control

To conduct heat, a medium is required (e.g. Atmosphere)

But at higher altitudes atmosphere is too thin, yet Wikipedia states temperatures in the [thermosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere) can rise to 2,000$^{\circ}$C

Electromagnetism can travel through vacuum, but is thermodynamics that simple? ISS uses radiators for thermal control, how do those "radiate" heat?

Is it just "radiation"?

Comment: "How is the Sun's heat transmitted to Earth?" is the first question you should be asking yourself.

Comment: I think there are several questions and some good answers about this already - it might be good to do a search within SXSE.

Comment: @uhoh It would be a better idea to define entropy for him.

Comment: @Raze go for it. I have so much entropy in my head that I can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: @uhoh I am afraid there is just as much entropy in my head than as it is in your head.

Comment: I thought I had a decent understanding of entropy before this thread, but I've suddenly realized there's much more entropy in my head than one can imagine.

Comment: @ITBear:  The temperature of a gas refers to the average speed of the gas molecules.  In other words, a high temperature is possible even if there is only one molecule.  However, the thinner the gas, the lower the heat transferred via conduction/convection.  Read the entire second paragraph of the Wikipedia link you provided in your question.